# applying multiple css classes to GWT

Tags: java, css, gwt

```css
.class1{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:20px;
}

.class2{
  background: #ffffff;
  color: grey;
}
```

and GWT method

```html
  private static final String STYLE2 = class2;
  private static final String STYLE1 = "class1";   
   
   
   
   HTML html = new HTML(htmlText);
    String text = html.getText();

    Label label = new Label();

    if (text.length() <= 50) {
      label.addStyleName(STYLE1);
    } else {
      text = text.substring(0, 500);
    }
    label.addStyleName(STYLE2);
    label.setText(text);
  }
```

what i want is when text become less than 50 apply both styles to label ... but it is overridden ... any help ??

Answer (score 4):

you can use setStyleName with class name and boolean parameter as below:

```
label.setStyleName(STYLE2,true);
```

here true is boolean value to add/append css class name.

An alternate solution can be to concatenate and apply those styles.

```
lable.addClassName(STYLE1 +" "+STYLE2);
```